# Is a variable declared under Grails(1.3.6) controller action and class variable thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, grails, model-view-controller, thread-safety

Is a variable declared under Grails(1.3.6) controller action and class variable thread safe? i.e

```
class TestController {
       String y //Is y thread-safe?
   def testAction = {
       String x //Is x thread-safe?
   }

}
```

Comment: Controller are request scoped (new y for each request).  and x is just a local var

Comment: In Grails 1.3.6, you're fine.  However, as of Grails 1.4.x, the default generated config for your Grails app changes the scope of controllers to "singleton" or "application", making your "y" variable thread-risky.   You shouldn't do this, anyway.  Don't add state to Controllers or Services directly.

Answer (score 0):

As cfrick responded, controllers are request scoped and all the variables will be reset at each call, so all of them are threadsafe. 
Depending on what you need to achieve, I'd suggest using session variables or **use a service** 
 (by default services are singleton - Only one instance of the service ever exists).

Comment: Perhaps you meant "controllers are request scoped and all the variables will be reset at each call, so ALL of them are threadsafe"?  If a new instance of the controller is made for each request, then the value can't be clobbered by another request.

Comment: @billjamesdev yes yes yes.. Editing it right now. Thanks for noticing. :)